# If you're not using an ORM, what is an efficient way to handle your boilerplate CRUD?

Tags: database, database-design, sqlalchemy

I am writing a forum-like component for a site, and it's use cases are pretty similar to something like reddit or quora, where things like topics, posts, groups, etc. are created. I am using python and sqlalchemy core, but still debating on whether or not I should just use the ORM. The real reason I don't want to use it is to avoid another component to deal with as things go on since I'm told the generated queries may cause problems and as things grow the you will have to deal with raw sql anyway for optimizations.

To the people who don't use an ORM to handle all your tedious CRUD and data marshalling, I'm just curious, do you write all of it out or do have another approach? How do you handle the tedious marshalling of data? Is there not better way that grabbing a result object and simply doing something like:

```
result = user_dao.get_user(userid)
user.name = result.name
user.email = result.email
user.passwd = result.password_hash
[...]
```

For certain objects/entities, this can become pretty cumbersome when there are 15+ attributes.

Comment: @Rapptz Sorry for the "link dumping", but there were very few chats open, and I figured I would you know, ask a question(noone ever seemed to mind before)... I didn't think anyone would mind much, what with the random things you guys were posting in there like videos of [hippos taking bowel-movements](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8809568#8809568),

Comment: @Doorknob [random tweets](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8810058#8810058), and a [shock site](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8809596#8809596) about a man stretching himself.  No one seemed to mind about those, but I guess posting a question about ORMs and python really crosses the line on being "off topic".

Comment: While linkdumping is bad, the question itself isn't. So, upvote.

Comment: @Bill Karwin I'd especially like to hear how you'd approach this since you sound like you get along quite fine with out ORMs

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the down votes are from the ORM fan boys of which I am not one.  I work as a professional software engineer and have used numerous ORMs, esp. nHibernate. Though the ORM tools where created to ease the level of database coding effort, and in some cases do, I find myself running into significant problems on larger projects.

If I already know databases and SQL well, why would I want to add yet another 3rd party (that I have to learn all about) between which has to work in a generic way and hope that it does so in a efficient and effective way?  If it doesn't I have to search high and low for some bass-akwards solution to force it to do what I want.

Then you might even go on to other projects where yet another ORM is chosen and you have to learn the ins and outs of that one too.......arg.

My preference is for code generation.  Some thing like [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) is a great tool you can learn once and apply to almost anything.  You can write your own, efficient code to work the way you want for say one table's CRUD, then turn it into a template which would generate the same CRUD for 100's of tables in seconds.

I start my apps with the table definitions, then run my templates for CRUD sprocs, then I have templates which create the DAL with straight ADO.Net which use those sprocs, then templates to create MVC models, BAL, Controllers, and Views.  Bam! I have a fully working app from the database.  Then I'll go about customizing things toward the end result.

I've also setup my templates to use "partial" classes so most of my generated code and custom code are separated, thus enabling me to regenerate code anytime I want to make changes to the templates to fix problems or add features, etc.  It's **very sweet** to add a feature, for example paging for large lists, and have it applied within minutes to 100s of tables.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of reasons to use an ORM outside of just running selection/update/etc statements.  For instance, it allows you to tie custom functionality to records in your application, it prevents SQL injection, it allows you to move more effectively to new class types behind your models, and a bunch of other things.

Yes, there are cases where you might need to write custom SQL for an application, but with join functionality in an ORM, this is not really all that common.  I know that DBIx for Perl offers 'virtual' types where you can toss in a custom select statement into the class, and still be able to write methods that are tied to that object.

The ability to tie methods to items that you select improves the DRY-ness of your code.  That combined with prevention of SQL injection leads me to suggest that you try to use an ORM and only not use one if you have a really good reason.  Anything that you use to handle the CRUD and data marshalling will just end up being a new 'ORM' anyhow, so why not let others do the hard work for you?

Comment: "Bound parameters" or other database driver parameter substitution will protect against SQL injection without the need for an ORM.

Comment: I'm assuming that is what an ORM is using in the background, but it prevents you from having to go through the entire prepare binding, hence allowing you to write less code.

Answer (score 2):

This question does not seem worthy of all the downvotes. I think the author has a legitimate concern here.

I've personally chosen an ORM hybrid. Something like SQL Alchemy tends to be a bit too heavy weight for what I'd like to accomplish, and it hasn't always generated the most efficient queries. I completely understand why you would hesitate.

This is especially true when grabbing fields from multiple tables. When I first started using SQL Alchemy I found that joining vs. multiple SELECT statements came as a tough decision. I've sort of shunned traditional ORMs since then.

Stephen Schmidt makes a [decent case](http://codemonkeyism.com/orms/) against ORMs in general, but I think there's a happy middle ground.

Maybe take a look at [PyORMish](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyormish)? It's really new, but fairly well tested. It's not really an ORM (hence the "ish"), but it reduces boiler plate code while providing simple access to raw SQL when needed.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of PyORMish*

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use ORM, you deal with raw SQL when you optimize. On the other hand, without ORM, you will deal with raw SQL when you write new code, debug the old code, test a feature and change your database scheme. That is totally different. ORMs resolve a lot of things with you. Be a man and face it: you don't want to learn another technology and you are inventing excuses.

Many ORMs optimize your SQL, they protect you from many attack types and they represent a new level of abstraction for your data model.

Believe me, you don't want to search for thousands of old, hard-coded SQL queries just because you renamed a column...

Comment: Oh I wasn't going to use hand written queries, but the [sqlalchemy expression language](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/tutorial.html). Its basically statements like this: "user.select(whereclause = (table.c.id = x)).execute()", which generate sql queries. I was planning on creating a bunch of DAO objects and implementing the [table gateway pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) using those types of objects.